# How to break a while loop when it is false to a certain condition

Tags: c, while-loop, integer

I was trying to make a program where if I enter an integer, the program would find out the bigger number and subtract it by the smaller number. This part, I got it.

The problem is, the infinite loop part.

I tried to get `type in two integers` keep on printing with the while loop, and `break` when at least one character is typed in.

For example, if I type in `2   @`, it would break.

But I couldn't find the write place to get the `break;` within the code and therefore whenever I enter a character it would keep on creating an infinite loop.

Is there any way to create a break in this code? I humbly ask for advice...

The following is the code which I couldn't put the `break`
(By the way, the reason I did the condition in while as `sizeof(i)==4 || sizeof(j)==4` was to make it so it would only enter an integer, since the size of an integer is 4)

```
int main()
{   
    int i, j;
    int result;

    while (sizeof(i)==4 || sizeof(j)==4){
        printf("type in two integers : ");
        scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
        if (i < j) {
            result = j - i;
        }
        else if (j < i){
            result = i - j;
        }

        printf("%d\n", result);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The bottom code is the one I tried to put `break` but failed (it kept creating an infinite loop)...

```
int main()
{   
    int i, j;
    int result;

    while (sizeof(i)==4 || sizeof(j)==4){
        if (sizeof(i) == 4 || sizeof(j) == 4) {
            printf("type in two integers : ");
            scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
            if (i < j) {
                result = j - i;
            }
            else if (j < i) {
                result = i - j;
            }

            printf("%d\n", result);
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and here's a code where I got rid of the `sizeof` and used `while(1)`, though there wasn't much change in the fact that the `break` didn't work...

```
int main()
{   
    int i, j;
    int result;

    while (1){
            printf("type in two integers : ");
            scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
            if (i < j) {
                result = j - i;
            }
            else if (j < i) {
                result = i - j;
            }

            printf("%d\n", result);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `while (2==scanf("%d %d", &i, &j)) `. If I understand your problem correctly it should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `sizeof(i)` to do run-time checks! This is a ***compile-time*** constant that, in your case (32-bit integers) will **always** evaluate to **4**.

In order to check that two valid integers have been given, you can check the **return value** of the `scanf` function (it gives the number of fields *successfully* scanned):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int result;

    while (1) {
        printf("type in two integers : ");
        if (scanf("%d %d", &i, &j) != 2) break; // Break here if we didn't get two integers
        if (i < j) {
            result = j - i;
        }
        else if (j < i) {
            result = i - j;
        }

        printf("%d\n", result);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask fir further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. If it's not a bother, could you please explain a little bit more on the part on ```scanf("%d %d", &i, &j) != 2```.  More specifically, on why it is ```2```? Is this because that true & true == 1 & 1 == 1 + 1 == 2?

Comment: As I said, `scanf` returns the *number of values* it has successfully read. If you enter `1 2` it will read two integers, and return `2` (success); if you enter `1 $` it will only read *one* integer and return `1` (failure); likewise, if you enter "& 2" it will return `0`.

Comment: But note: there are many dangers in using the `scanf` function! If you enter `2 0.1` it will **successfully** read two integers (`2` and `0`) but, next time round, will **fail** - because the `.` character is left in the input buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the whole concept of endless loop with break inside if.
Make a condition for the loop based on the return value of `scanf()`, that is practically what it is designed for.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    /* always init everything */
    int i=0, j=0;
    int result=0;

    printf("type in two integers : ");
    while (2==scanf("%d %d", &i, &j))
    {
        if (i < j) {
            result = j - i;
        }
        else /* removed second if, to have a meaningful result for i==j */
        {
            result = i - j;
        }

        printf("%d\n", result);
        printf("type in two integers : ");            
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'd probably actually use `do {...} while (...)` with a variable storing the return value of `scanf()`for being used in the loop condition. I'd consider it more elegant for not having to copy the print, but I kept it closer to your code structure.

More comments on your code:

- as explained in comments, `sizeof()` works differently than you seem to think; it is static and does not change at runtime and hence cannot be used in a loop condition
- with `while (sizeof(i)==4 || sizeof(j)==4){if (sizeof(i) == 4 || sizeof(j) == 4){/* a */} else {/* b */}`, b cannot ever be reached, because the conditions of `while` and `if` are identical
- check the possible outcomes of the if conditions inside the loop, you are leaving the one with `i==j` undefined and return an uninitialised value
- always init all variables as a habit
- for a good MRE include the include lines

On your request, here is a proposal for the do-while alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    /* always init everything */
    int i=0, j=0;
    int result=0;
    int iScanned=0;

    do 
    {
        printf("type in two integers : ");
        iScanned=scanf("%d %d", &i, &j); /* keep the return value for loop */

        if (i < j) {
            result = j - i;
        }
        else /* removed second if, to have a meaningful result for i==j */
        {
            result = i - j;
        }

        if(2==iScanned) printf("%d\n", result); /* if to avoid awkward last output */
    } while (2==iScanned);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the specific comments on my code as well as an alternative code! Also, I'd like to give it a try on the ```do {...} while (...)```. If it's not a bother, would it be possible for a code using this? so I can match if what I write is right?

Comment: My pleasure. Turns out that it is less elegant than I thought, because I could not avoid an additional `if` for pretty output. I still like it slightly better than the `while` alternative, because I prefer the additional but straight-forward `if` to doubling the output line. Output lines, in my opinion/experience, are more likely to be changed than logic (once tested). And now, is your `do-while` code similar?

Comment: Note, I agree with @AdrianMole comment-warning on the other answer, which absolutely applies equally well to mine. More on pitfalls with scanf can be found in this very interesting article: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html